# Msgbox() does not disappear on pressing O.K

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code where a msgbox pops up notifying a duplicate value.

Problem is the msgbox() does not go away on clicking ok and the code gets stuck.

```
Dim row As Integer 
Dim counter As Integer 

Range("c2").Activate 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

For counter = 0 To 688

If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Value And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 9).Value Then

MsgBox ("Found a duplicate")

Else ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

End If

Next counter
```

Comment: You put that MsgBox() in the loop, so it could potentially pop-up 688 times. Correct your business logic and VBA code. Best regards,

Comment: [msgBox Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251821.aspx)

Comment: Your counter is pointless. It only repeats "If statement" 689 times.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when the **If** is *True* the MsgBox is displayed and ActiveCell is never incremented.  Therefore the MsgBox gets re-displayed 687 times!